# Regular Expressions in python, matching either space or nothing?

Tags: python, regex

Basically, I want it to match 'asdf 78' and '78' but not 'asdf78'. So basically, it matches just 78, but not if there's any other character thats not space attached to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's ...

```
(?:^|\s)78
```

`(?: exp )` can be ommited. Though, it tells Python you don't want to know what it catched (you just want to know if it catched it wathever it is) (so we don't catch what we don't need; this is a good habit)

\s is any white space (you can use a simple space if you prefer)

The rest should be ok if you know regular expressions a bit.

Comment: Note that this will still allow "78asdf" -- to apply the same rule to the end, try `(?:^|\s)78(?:\s|$)`